How to change the color of a class that you call in VSCode?

Hi, I'm wondering how I can change the names of classes that I'm calling in VSCode?
For example, the lines that are
self.layernorm_1 = nn.LayerNorm(n_embed)

self.attention = SelfAttention(n_head, n_embed)

etc...
in my VSCode, "nn.LayerNorm", "SelfAttention" are white instead of green like in a demo video I've been following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBKpAp_6TGI&t=8237s) [second screenshot)

I've tried fiddling around with a few tokenColorCustomizations in settings.json like
"entity.name.type.class" 
"support.class"
"support.function"
"entity.name.class"

but no changes I've made have targeted the right thing. Any ideas? Thank you!

use the TextMate Scope inspector to find the unique scope name for what you want to color customize, is not unique scope adjust the language grammar, if you change theme do they have a color

The one in the video has probably changed the color theme. You can change the VSCode theme with Ctrl+k,Ctrl+S shortcut.
Offical doc:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes
If you want to create your own theme, then check this out:
How can I create my own theme for vs code?
